# how can I retrieve values from array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I make perform HTTP Request by this command

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error)
```

and get back my data in JSONDecoder, then I do this

```
let groceryPro = try decoder.decode(GroceryProduct.self, from: data!)
```

where my GroceryProduct is:

```
    struct GroceryProduct: Codable  { 
   var data: [Data1] 
   } 
   struct Data1: Codable {
   var id: String? 
   var name: String? 
   var system_name: String? 
   var type: String? 
   var lang: String? 
   var is_global: Int?
}
```

I got a big array, this is one value from it, in total there are ≈ 700:

```
Data1(id: Optional("9"), name: Optional("войти"), system_name: Optional("login"), type: Optional("button"), lang: Optional("ru"), is_global: Optional(1))
```

I need to call the array that matches some requirements, for an example, if `system_name : "Esc"` then I need to get this array

Comment: At a lower level of knowledge, you create an empty array, you do a for loop on that big array, and each time there is an object that match your requirement, you append it to the array. That's the basic of algorithmic. At a higher level, you can use `filter()`.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez yes, it's helped, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

try this :

```
let arrEseSystem = groceryPro.data.filter{ $0.system_name == “Esc" }
```

Comment: `"Esc”` *******

Comment: thanks, it works, exactly what I need.

Comment: glad that work for you, can you make my answer as accepted answer.